# rewrite all the pages to page name only in my web site

Tags: php, html, url-rewrite-module

I have created a php web site. Here I have implemented the clean URL in .htaccess file. I need to display mu link 
`mydomain/index.php` to `mydomain/index`

So I have used

```
RewriteRule index index.php
```

But I have lot of files. So how will I write a common rule for this entire page?

E:g

```
RewriteRule hotels hotels.php
```

Thanks

Comment: Search a little, and you'll find thousands of exact duplicates :-)

Comment: http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
#Setup
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#Remove trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=permanent,QSA]

#Your thing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This is pretty clever: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f`